# query multiple columns php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

new to php and am enrolled on a course, so can ask tutor tomorrow if this is more complicated than i think it might be!

I have an sql query, and it works fine. But I am trying to add and 'and' in the select statement.

This is what I have at the minute

```
$query = "SELECT * from table1 where table1.age <= " . $_POST['min_age'] ;
```

I have a 'region' input on my linked html page and want results to be returned only if the min_age and region values match those inputted by the user.

I have tried adding an 'and where' but it doesn't work and I am not sure if it is because of the multiple "'s or if what I am trying to do needs a different method?

Thanks

Comment: it should not be "and where". Can you post the current query that you have (with multiple wheres or something like that ) ?

Comment: WHERE column=stuff adn someothercolumn=stuff

Comment: You only need to use 'where' once in a query. WHERE x=y AND x>4

Comment: ok thanks but I tried that too - so would I need to start with " again after [min_age] and before the and?

Answer (score 2):

If you need multiple conditions, just separate them with `AND`:

```
... WHERE table1.age <= ? AND table1.region = ?
```

No need to use `WHERE` again. Just like you wouldn't need to use `if()` more than once if you were writing a complex condition in PHP.

---

PS: This isn't directly related to your question, but you should get into the habit of *not* putting $_POST or $_GET variables directly into your SQL queries. It's a good way to get hacked! Ask your tutor about "SQL injection," or read my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies).

I know you're just starting out, but if you were training to be an electrician, you would place a high priority on learning how to avoid being electrocuted or how to avoid causing a fire.

Here's how I would write your query using mysqli. One advantage of using query parameters is you never need to worry about where you start and end your quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT * from table1 where table1.age <= ? AND table1.region = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);

$stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST["min_age"], $_POST["region"]);
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
```

The other good habit I'm showing here is to *always* report if prepare() or execute() return an error.

---

If you must interpolate variables into your SQL, first make sure you protect the variables either by coercing the value to an integer, or else by using a proper escaping function like mysqli_real_escape_string().  *Don't* put $_POST variables directly into the string. Also you don't have to stop and restart the quotes if you use PHP's syntax for embedding variables directly in double-quoted strings:

```
$age = (int) $_POST["min_age"];
$region = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["region"]);
$query = "SELECT * from table1 where table1.age <= {$age} 
    AND table1.region = '{$region}'";
```

Comment: ok thanks but I tried that too - so would I need to start with " again after [min_age] and before the and?

Comment: ok brilliant thanks i will ask about that! For now though (as this is only a test iam doing, it wont go live) how would i add the and without "'s interfering with each other?